# Opencart multistore "domain.com/aaa" instead of "aaa.domain.com"

Tags: .htaccess, opencart, multistore

Anyone can help to have "domain.com/store1/any-product" instead of "store1.domain.com/any-product"? The second is what I have and the first is what I would like to have.

Maybe some .htaccess code added? Anything else, please?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve that by using the following rule in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^store1.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/store1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

What the above does is if the condition for `store1.example.com` is met, then it will rewrite the URL to `example.com/store1`. This will also work for any other directories you have as a part of it. So it would become `example.com/store1/about` for example.

Make sure you clear your cache **before** you test this.

Comment: Well, it works as you wrote but it is not what I would like it to be...
Without your code I put in a browser store1.example.com/about and all is OK. With your code when I type it, it is changed to example.com/store1/about and it does not work at all. 
What I want is to type in a browser example.com/store1/about and it should work as store1.example.com/about without changing visible URL.

Comment: You can't _internally rewrite_ to a different host. The above `RewriteRule` will _implicitly_ trigger an external (302) redirect. If you want to "rewrite" across hosts then you need to use mod_proxy (`P` flag with mod_rewrite) - but this might require some additional _server_ configuration.